# How to concat few parquet files with same schema?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, parquet

I have some parquets files - let's say 10 -  with same schema.
And what I want to do, is merge it to one parquet. I need to have a one parquet file to process it in delta lake faster.

I found some options, here on stack, using hive but I don't use it.

There is simple way to concat parquets file in one? For example using spark?
I tried do it by reading to pandas all dataframes, then merge it into one dataframe and save as parquet but 1) it's seem very ugly and not efficient 2) I faced with many errors, and structure of the final parquet was weird.

So summary - my question is:

- Is there a simple way to concat several parquets files with the same schema not reading all to memory in pandas as pandas df? For example in spark?

After concat I need to create Delta Table from that parquet, that's why I need to keep structure of file

** UPDATE **

I tried a suggestion from @samkart and:

I just read all parquets in that way:

```
df=spark.read.parquet('Downloads/P4.parquet', 'Downloads/P3.parquet', 'Downloads/P2.parquet', 'Downloads/P1.parquet')
```

and everything looks fine, I mean I can create temporaryView and query it by sql. I see all records from all files.

But when I try save it as parquet:

```
df.coalesce(1).write.parquet('Downloads/new/export')
```

I got very long error, totally unclear for me:

```
> 22/11/03 16:51:15 ERROR FileFormatWriter: Aborting job
> 795363da-8493-40bf-8da8-b81b014f38df. java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
> 'boolean
> org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(java.lang.String,
> int)'
>         at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:793)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1218)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.list(FileUtil.java:1423)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.listStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:601)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1972)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:2014)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.listStatus(ChecksumFileSystem.java:761)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1972)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:2014)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.getAllCommittedTaskPaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:334)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJobInternal(FileOutputCommitter.java:404)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:377)
>         at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputCommitter.commitJob(ParquetOutputCommitter.java:48)
>         at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitJob(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:192)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$25(FileFormatWriter.scala:267)
>         at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.timeTakenMs(Utils.scala:642)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:267)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:186)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:113)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:111)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:125)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:98)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:109)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:169)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:95)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:98)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:94)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:584)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:176)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:584)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:560)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:94)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:81)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:79)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:116)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:860)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:390)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:363)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:239)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:793)
>         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)
>         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
>         at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
>         at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
>         at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
>         at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>         at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
>         at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
>         at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
>         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [I 2022-11-03 16:53:09.694 ServerApp] Saving file at /Untitled.ipynb
> 22/11/03 17:10:48 ERROR FileFormatWriter: Aborting job
> 2d1db0cd-686c-4eb0-938a-e719faee4aff. java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
> 'boolean
> org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(java.lang.String,
> int)'
>         at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:793)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1218)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.list(FileUtil.java:1423)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.listStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:601)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1972)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:2014)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.listStatus(ChecksumFileSystem.java:761)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1972)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:2014)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.getAllCommittedTaskPaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:334)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJobInternal(FileOutputCommitter.java:404)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:377)
>         at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputCommitter.commitJob(ParquetOutputCommitter.java:48)
>         at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitJob(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:192)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$25(FileFormatWriter.scala:267)
>         at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.timeTakenMs(Utils.scala:642)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:267)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:186)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:113)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:111)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:125)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:98)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:109)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:169)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:95)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:98)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:94)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:584)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:176)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:584)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:560)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:94)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:81)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:79)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:116)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:860)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:390)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:363)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:239)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:793)
>         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)
>         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
>         at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
>         at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
>         at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
>         at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>         at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
>         at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
>         at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
>         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Comment: how did you write those parquet files? if spark, then you can write it using `df.coalesce(1).write.parquet()`. the `coalesce(1)` will merge all partitions into single partition and hence spark will write a single file. but do it if absolutely necessary, as it can deteriorate performance for larger data.

Comment: Do you mean: how I create that 10 parquets? I'm using pyarrow. I have some files in JSON, and preparing schema. Then I read JSON in pyarrow with that schema, and just save as .parquet file

Comment: then you can read the parquet files in spark using `df=spark.read.parquet('path/to/folder/where/files/reside')` and then use spark to write a single file `df.coalesce(1).write.parquet('path/to/export/folder)`

Comment: @samkart I just tried your way to do that, and I faced with new errors. Can U look at update in post ? Did I everything ok?

Comment: could you add one more paragraph of the traceback? there should be a line with the word exception

Comment: @samkart I updated post with whole error

Comment: `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError` look for details on this. I believe it's related to path of Hadoop executables.